# 2D Peak Algorithm fails to find the peak

Tags: algorithm, 2d

I just started an MIT course on algorithm, and we were taught the 2D Peak Finding algo. I tried dry running and implementing it yet the algo seems to be failing for this input.

```
{5, 0, 3, 2}
{1, 1, 2, 4}
{1, 2, 4, 4}
```

This is the Algorithm:

```
• Pick middle column j = m/2
• Find global maximum on column j at (i,j)
• Compare(i,j−1),(i,j),(i,j+1)
• Pick left columns of(i,j−1)>(i,j)
• Similarly for right
• (i,j) is a 2D-peak if neither condition holds ← WHY?
• Solve the new problem with half the number of columns.
• When you have a single column, find global maximum and you‘re done.
```

Update, Here is the code which I tried and doesn't seem to be working:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

const int MAX = 100; 

int findMax(int arr[][MAX], int rows, int mid, int& max) 
{ 
    int max_index = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { 
        if (max < arr[i][mid]) { 
            max = arr[i][mid]; 
            max_index = i; 
        } 
    } 
    return max_index; 
} 

int findPeakRec(int arr[][MAX], int rows, int columns, int mid) 
{ 
    int max = 0; 
    int max_index = findMax(arr, rows, mid, max); 
    if (mid == 0 || mid == columns - 1) 
        return max; 
    if (max >= arr[max_index][mid - 1] && max >= arr[max_index][mid + 1]) 
        return max; 
    if (max < arr[max_index][mid - 1]) 
        return findPeakRec(arr, rows, columns, mid - ceil((double)mid / 2)); 
    return findPeakRec(arr, rows, columns, mid + ceil((double)mid / 2)); 
} 

int findPeak(int arr[][MAX], int rows, int columns) 
{ 
    return findPeakRec(arr, rows, columns, columns / 2); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int arr[][MAX] = { { 5, 0, 3, 2 }, 
                       { 1, 1, 2, 4 }, 
                       { 1, 2, 4, 4 }, 
                       { 3, 2, 0, 1 } }; 
    int rows = 4, columns = 4; 
    cout << findPeak(arr, rows, columns); 
    return 0; 
}
```

this is how I implemented the algorithm.

Comment: Tried and debugging yet? What were your findings?

Comment: Needs details or clarity

Comment: Edit your question, and add the code that you have a problem with. What does `Pickleftcolumnsof` do? *" ← WHY?"* ... that seems to be a second question. Please focus on one question only.

Comment: I see you added spaces to "Pick left columns of", but what does `Pick left columns of (i,j−1)>(i,j)` do? Adding the actual code is the only way to pinpoint where you might have an issue.

Comment: @trincot I was using my phone hence just edited, the problem is not the code, its the implementation of the algorithm.

this is the original reference of the study material:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/MIT6_006F11_lec01.pdf

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni the algo?

Comment: @trincot pick left columns implies choosing the value to the left of the current column

Comment: Code = implementation. Not sure what you mean that the problem is not the code. If you don't have code you don't have an implementation, and hence no problem with the implementation either. So what is your question if you don't have code?

Comment: @trincot i meant the code is just the implementation of the algo, nothing wrong with it I checked. The algorithm, seems to be faulty to me.

Comment: Your code outputs 4. That is correct. Do you have an example where it gives the wrong output?

Comment: @trincot i could be wrong but the first input i.e (0,0) is 5 which is the peak, shouldn't it point there?

Comment: OK. I think you missed a correct definition of "peak". The algorithm for peak finding intends to find a *local* maximum, not necessarily the global maximum. For a global maximum the algorithm is trivial, you just look for the maximum value with a row by row scan. But **peak** finding can be more efficient as not all values need to be inspected.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is correct (Just a spelling mistake in the fourth bullet point: "of" should read "if").

You missed a correct definition of "peak". The algorithm for peak finding intends to find a *local* maximum, not necessarily the *global* maximum. For a global maximum the algorithm is trivial, you just look for the maximum value with a row by row scan.

But peak finding can be more efficient as not all values need to be inspected.